# function Reverse() in XPath 2.0 : how can use it to evaluate an expression?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Please go easy on me , this is my first time using `XPath 2.0` :)

Given the following code :

```
import net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression;
import net.sf.saxon.expr.StaticContext;
import net.sf.saxon.functions.CompileTimeFunction;
import net.sf.saxon.sort.Reverser;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;

public class MyReverse extends CompileTimeFunction {

    public Expression simplify(StaticContext env) throws XPathException {
        Reverser a = new Reverser(argument[0]);
        return a.simplify(env);
    }

}
```

I want to reverse the query :

```
String query = "inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title";
Object myQuery= xpath.evaluate(query,doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

for my XML file (**I can attach the XML file if you wish ,so please say so if it's indeed required!**)

Now from my understanding if I do this :

```
MyReverse rev = new MyReverse();
```

then if I try to use the method `evaluateAsString` like this : `rev.evaluateAsString(arg0)`
then `arg0` should be a `XPathContext` object .

How can I use my query with the above method ?

Regards

***EDIT 1:***

In the example that dear Mr. @Dimitre Novatchev wrote , what is needed is all the nodes from node `X` , to the upper side of the document.

However , if one of `X's` siblings , has children , then I need to present the sibling and only then his (the sibling's) children (and after that move on to the next sibling , and the same all over again) , and **not** the child of the sibling & only then - the sibling .

I'm sorry for not mentioning & explaining this earlier

thanks again :)

Comment: XPath 2.0 has a `reverse` function so you can solve that on the XPath expression level with e.g. `reverse(inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title)`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I know ,but I want to do this on the level of functions  , is it possible ?

Comment: I am not really familiar with details of the Saxon XPath API so I can't help you with that.

Comment: @ron: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying in the Edit. * Reverse* means: By definition `reverse(n1,n2n, nM) = (nM, n(M-1), ...n2, n1`. You want the selected nodes in reverse document order -- and this is the result when the `reverse()` function is applied on the selected node-set. If you now want something different, please, ask a new question.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: This reverse is indeed a little bit odd , however the produced output should start from the current node that we start from , and then going up . Now , when I come across a sibling , if that sibling has children , then present the sibling with all his children . After that , we continue up the scale to the next in line sibling on our tour up the scale ...

Comment: @ron: I would like this explained in your new question. And please, don't use the word "reverse", because it means something different from what you want. Good night.

Comment: OK, I think what you want is: `reverse(/inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter)//title`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just evaluate this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
reverse(/inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title)
```

**Here is an XSLT -based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "reverse(/inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter//title)
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (taken from your previous question):

```
<inventory>
    <book num="myBook1">
        <title>Lindsy Boxer</title>
        <author>James Patterson</author>
        <publisher>LittleBig</publisher>
        <price>18.21</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>
            <paragraph>
                    This is the 
                <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="alexCrossImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph>
                    This is the 
                <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="alexCrossImageAnother.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
            <section>
                <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
                <paragraph>
                        This is the 
                    <emph>first</emph>paragraph for chapter TWO section ONE.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph>
                        This is the 
                    <emph>second</emph> paragraph for chapter TWO section ONE.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </section>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Chapter C</title>
            <paragraph>
                    This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="myBook2">
        <title>Jack Reacher Series</title>
        <author>Lee Child</author>
        <author>Jonny White</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <price>5.99</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Jack Reacher - Chapter ONE</title>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Jack Reacher - Chapter TWO</title>
            <paragraph>
                    This is the 
                <emph>second</emph> paragraph of SECOND book chapter TWO.
                <image file="Jack_Reacher_Picture_Top_Sniper_US_Army.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="myBook3">
        <title>Alex Cross - Double Cross</title>
        <author>James Patterson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>17.30</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Alex Cross - Double Cross - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
    </book>
</inventory>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and the resulting sequence of nodes is copied to the output:**

```
<title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
<title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
<title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>
```

As we can see, the sequence contains the wanted elements and in reverse-document order -- exactly as requested.

As for how to evaluate an XPath expression with Saxon 9.x, read the appropriate documentation: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.xml which has a pointer to a fully working code example.

**UPDATE**:

In a comment the OP has indicated that he needs the `chapter` elements in reverse document order, but their title elements in document order.

To avhieve this, use:

```
reverse(/inventory/book/chapter[3]/preceding-sibling::chapter)//title
```

Comment: The link is broken , do you maybe any other alternative ? 10x !

Comment: @ron: I can visit the link OK. Obviously, you have internet connectivity problems.

Comment: I did not notice at first ,but the "reverse" function doesn't do what is needed. Please take a look at your output , and compare it with the requested one (this is the requested) : "        *  <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B</title>
         *  <title>Along Came A Spider - Chapter B - section 1</title>
         *  <title>Alex Cross Is Back - Chapter A</title>" ... as you can see , for the first two entries , the first line should be the second one (and the 2nd should be the 1st) ....

Comment: @ron: In your question you haven't explicitly specified what is "requested".  You just say: "I want to reverse the query". Now, this means to me that you want to get a sequence of the selected elements, but in reverse order. And the `reverse()` function does exactly that. If you want another order, then you must edit the question, delete the word "reverse" and explain exactly what new order is wanted. Or better, start a new question and this time pay moreattention to what you say.

Comment: @ron: I updated this answer with an XPath expression that selects the elements according to your new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You're fiddling about with internal Saxon implementation classes which you should not need to use and which you clearly don't understand. You should be doing the work you want (reversing the order of a set of nodes) in the XPath expression, not in the calling Java code.